# How to prevent Jupyter Notebook download PDF from printing outside of margin?

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, via "File- Download as - PDF via LaTeX (.pdf)", I downloaded my notebook as a pdf file. However, many of my code blocks get printed outside of the PDF page margins - i.e. for longer code lines, they get cut out at the pdf page right border. Any way to fix this so that I can have a readable PDF doc (other than manually add hard returns for each line or [the way suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291770/4896087)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  Ultimately, I found the answer at:

http://www.markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/customizing-nbconvert-pdf.html

Basically, it involves adding a custom latex template that wraps lines.  He also adjusts some of the font sizes so that the need for wrapping is less.

I did find one bug.  His code is missing the final end macro line:

```
((*- endmacro *))
```

I put the file in *~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/templates/latex* .  The location will vary depending on your installation. I'm using anaconda 4.3.1 (Jupyter 4.3.1 as well?)

Actually what I did was rename the existing article.tplx, changed the "extends 'article.tplx' " reflect the new name, and wrote the new template as article.tplx .  That way I can change the templates without having to restart the server.